# Going well vs. going swell

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I got a text from a US native saying:

> `Hope everything is going swell'

I had never heard that before. Is it common? Where is better to use swell instead of well?

Comment: Wrong. Swell is a dated informal adverb meaning "very well"  not a typo!

Comment: True, mea culpa! It's an adverb meaning 'very well.' Reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Hope everything is going swell'

It's a perfectly valid construction, swell is a slang form of 'well' as far as I can judge.
[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/swell) gives its definition as 'first-rate; fine'... right down at the bottom, last entry

It used to be common, though the place you'd really hear it is Hollywood movies from the 1940's. [It's fallen out of use these days.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going%20swell&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoing%20swell%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: "swell is a slang form of 'well' as far as I can judge" It looks like they have different Old English roots.

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking to a surfer could it be right, Cause with a good swell is the synonym of "Good Time for waves". So in this case, I will assume "Is going Swell" like the person is surfing the waves or circumstances  in real life, catching waves everywhere.

Comment: I don't think this idiom is surfer slang, can you provide a citation.

Comment: It's best not to guess at what something *could* mean. If you're unsure, either leave it in a comment or don't post it at all. In the surfer's case, "swell" is a noun referring to waves, but in the OP, "swell" is an adverb that means "well".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).